Debian dist-upgrade from Bookworm to Trixie failed with multiple dependency issues
I followed the guide from this page https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade to upgrade my Debian distribution. Everything went well until the final full-upgrade and a dependency hell broke, as follows.
$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
[sudo] password for karim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 girepository-tools : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (= 2.82.4-1) but it is not installed
 gnome-system-monitor : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 kwayland-integration : Depends: libqt5core5t64 (>= 5.15.2~) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libqt5gui5t64 (>= 5.15.2~) but it is not installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.2~) but it is not installed
                        Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-15
                        Depends: qtwayland-client-abi-5-15-15
 libadwaita-1-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.40.0-6) but 5.36.0-7+deb12u1 is installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.40.0
 libappstream5 : Depends: libcurl3t64-gnutls (>= 7.63.0) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 : Depends: libatk1.0-0t64 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.34.0) but it is not installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.37) but 2.40-4 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.36-9+deb12u8) but 2.40-4 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.36-9+deb12u8) but 2.40-4 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.36-9+deb12u8)
 libcairo-gobject2 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.68.0) but it is not installed
 libcairo2 : Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installed
 libcrypt-dev : Depends: libcrypt1 (= 1:4.4.33-2) but 1:4.4.36-5 is installed
 libedataserver-1.2-27t64 : Depends: libcamel-1.2-64t64 (>= 3.53.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.68.0) but it is not installed
 libgck-2-2 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgcr-4-4 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgio-2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (= 2.82.4-1) but it is not installed
                  Recommends: libgio-2.0-dev-bin (= 2.82.4-1)
                  Recommends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.82.4-1)
 libgirepository-2.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (= 2.82.4-1) but it is not installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.82.4-1)
 libglib2.0-dev-bin : Depends: libgio-2.0-dev-bin (= 2.82.4-1)
 libglibmm-2.4-1t64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.62.0) but it is not installed
 libglibmm-2.68-1t64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.82) but it is not installed
 libgnome-autoar-0-0 : Depends: libarchive13t64 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgnome-bg-4-2t64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 : Depends: gnome-desktop3-data (>= 44.1-1) but 43.2-2 is installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgnome-rr-4-2t64 : Depends: gnome-desktop3-data (>= 44.1-1) but 43.2-2 is installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgs10 : Depends: libcups2t64 (>= 2.3~b6) but it is not installed
           Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installed
 libgtk-4-1 : Depends: libcups2t64 (>= 1.7.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installed
              Recommends: libgtk-4-media-gstreamer
 libgtkmm-4.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.44.0) but it is not installed
 libgtop-2.0-11 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libgudev-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libharfbuzz-gobject0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not installed
 libharfbuzz0b : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.32.0) but it is not installed
 libical3t64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libngtcp2-crypto-gnutls8 : Depends: libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
 libnm0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.44.0) but it is not installed
          Depends: libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.7.2) but it is not installed
 libnsl2 : Depends: libtirpc3t64 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 252.30-1~deb12u2)
 libpango-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.34.0) but it is not installed
 libpangomm-2.48-1t64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.34.0) but it is not installed
 libpangoxft-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libpng-dev : Depends: libpng16-16t64 (= 1.6.44-3) but it is not installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5core5t64 (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libqt5gui5t64 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installed
                Depends: libqt5gui5t64 (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installed or
                         libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libqt5network5t64 (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-15
                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-15-15
 librtmp1 : Depends: libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.8.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libhogweed6t64 but it is not installed
            Depends: libnettle8t64 but it is not installed
 libsoup-2.4-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.62.0) but it is not installed
 libsoup-3.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libsoup-gnome-2.4-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.38.0) but it is not installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.14-1~deb12u2)
 libtirpc-dev : Depends: libtirpc3t64 (= 1.3.4+ds-1.3+b1) but it is not installed
 libtotem-plparser18 : Depends: libarchive13t64 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 libwireplumber-0.5-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.68) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 1.1.81) but it is not installed
 libxmlb2 : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.54.0) but it is not installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.40)
 mutter-common-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.80.0) but it is not installed
 network-manager : Depends: libcurl3t64-gnutls (>= 7.24.0) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.68.0) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.7.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not installed
 openssh-sftp-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:9.2p1-2+deb12u3)
 pavucontrol : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.32.0) but it is not installed
 pipewire : Depends: pipewire-bin (= 0.3.65-3+deb12u1)
 pipewire-bin : Depends: libpipewire-0.3-modules (= 1.2.7-1) but 0.3.65-3+deb12u1 is installed
                Depends: libasound2t64 (>= 1.2.5) but it is not installed
                Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (= 1.2.7-1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not installed
 pipewire-pulse : Depends: pipewire (= 1.2.7-1) but 0.3.65-3+deb12u1 is installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.11.2-1+b1) but 3.12.6-1 is installed
 qml-module-qtqml : Depends: libqt5core5t64 (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-15-15
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.15.15+dfsg~) but 5.15.8+dfsg-3 is installed
                              Depends: libqt5core5t64 (>= 5.15.15+dfsg~) but it is not installed
                              Depends: libqt5gui5t64 (>= 5.15.15+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.15+dfsg~) but it is not installed
                              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-15
                              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-15-15
 samba-common-bin : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1) but 2:4.21.2+dfsg-3 is installed
 vlc-plugin-base : Depends: vlc-data (= 3.0.21-0+deb12u1) but 3.0.21-2 is installed
 wget : Depends: libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.8.1) but it is not installed
        Depends: libnettle8t64 but it is not installed
 wireplumber : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.68) but it is not installed
               Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
               Depends: pipewire (>= 1.0.2) but 0.3.65-3+deb12u1 is installed
 x11-apps : Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installed
 xdg-desktop-portal : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.70.0) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 0.3.1) but it is not installed
 xwayland : Depends: libtirpc3t64 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I don't have backups of my system. Is there a chance I can save my system, even if it needs an intricate surgery?

Did you Try 'apt --fix-broken install' as suggested? For future reference, did you read https://www.debian.org/releases/trixie/release-notes/upgrading.en.html as well?

Also, Trixie is the testing release, i.e., it will be the release candidate for the next stable release after bookworm.  That is why @Bravo posted the link we urge you to read.

One way the debian instructions you linked to differs from instructions I've used in the past (also on Debian, but I can't find the page) ... after editing the apt source files, I do apt update then apt upgrade --without-new-packages then apt full-upgrade - note the use of apt rather than apt-get
